# Error with "argparse.ArgumentParser" in python

Tags: python

This is giving a wierd error:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    import json

    from evaluation import cross_validation
    from predictor import PhraseSentimentPredictor

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument("filename")
    config = parser.parse_args()
    config = json.load(open(config.filename))
```

Error:

> ```
> **usage: generate_kaggle_submission.py [-h] filename
>     generate_kaggle_submission.py: error: too few arguments**
> ```

Please help

Comment: Can you show how you are running the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you invoke the python program with the `filename` argument.

---

If you want to make the `filename` argument optional, specify `nargs` with `?` or `*`:

```
parser.add_argument("filename", nargs='?')
# OR with default
parser.add_argument("filename", nargs='?', default='default_filename')
```

See [`nargs` - `argparse` - Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs) for other available options.